# Axios post form urlencoded requests application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: node.js, post, axios

I'm trying to make a requests post with axios, sending that postdata from a checkbox and submit button, but I don't know how to do this correctly with axios, I would appreciate your help
`

```
const URI = "https://www.guadeloupe.gouv.fr/booking/create/12828/0"
    const data = "condition=on&nextButton=Effectuer+une+demande+de+rendez-vous"
    const headers = {
    'Content-Type':           'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent':             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding':        'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Origin':                 'https://www.guadeloupe.gouv.fr'
    }
    
    const resp = await axios.post(URI,data,headers)
```

with insomnia = [INSONMIA POST REQUEST SCREEN SHUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHlcv.jpg)

CHECKBOX = [PHOTO CHECKBOX SUBMIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1V05.jpg)

Comment: Can you share a checkbox(or Postman) screen shut? It help to understand what kinds of key/value needs to call axios.

Comment: I appreciate your help, updated, screen shut available, thanks you @BenchVue [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHlcv.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your update image. It helps to understand the next Button's `+` is just space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test with real REST server but I can suggest this code.

It's base on your image and code.

```js
const resp = await axios.post(URI,
            new URLSearchParams({
                'condition': 'condition',
                'nextButton': 'Effectuer une demande de rendez vous' 
            }),
            {
                headers:
                {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            })
```

Comment: makes sure, your `axios` version is v1.2.1

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I had already tried this way, and it doesn't work, I can't understand why it doesn't work, it's as if it didn't send the data, with potsman, insomnia it works perfectly, but I tried with axios, fetch, request-promise and it does not work @BenchVue

Comment: OK, without real test with token, hard to find solution. good luck!